# Undispatched/uncatchable user-mode exceptions (Windows x86)

Tags: windows, exception, x86

There are various circumstances in which a Windows user-mode process can trigger an exception for which `KiUserExceptionDispatcher` is never called, meaning it can't be caught by user-mode code.

For example, overflowing the stack will raise `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION`, but the kernel handles the exception itself by growing the stack. Similarly, exceptions don't seem to ever be dispatched to user-mode if `ESP` points to non-writable memory (understandably).

**What other exceptions triggered by user-mode code are not dispatched through `KiUserExceptionDispatcher`?**